# How to declare optional class property with generic `Results`

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a lot of `Object` subclasses which all of them conforms to some protocol (`Transport` for ex.) and I don't know which type of objects (`Car` or `Bus` for ex.) will be displayed, it depends on some parameters and therefore I want to have some generic computed value which can return `Results` of `Object`s based on `Type` enum value. Can I do that without casting `Results` to array?

```
protocol Transport { }
class Car: Object, Transport { }
class Bus: Object, Transport { }

// #1
var array: Array<Transport>? {
  return [Car(), Bus()]
}

// #2
var results: Results<Object>? {
  if displayCars {
    realm?.objects(Car.self)
  } else {
    realm?.objects(Bus.self)
  } 
}
```

№1 will be fine but №2 will not compile because:
`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Results<Car>?' to return type 'Results<Object>?'`

#### Update

```
// Another example.
var objects: Results<Object>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  if displayCars {
    objects = realm.objects(Car.self)
  }      

}
```

Compile error: `Cannot assign value of type 'Results<Car>?' to type 'Results<Object>?'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will probably have to turn `Results<Car>` into `[Car]` in order for this to work. The built-in Swift collections are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), but any user-defined Swift generic type (including user-defined collections) is invariant. There's no way right now to specify otherwise.